# Spark DataFrame wrap struct<.. into array of struct<

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to modify a Dataframe which is generated by an external library.
I receive a Dataframe with this schema:

```
root
 |-- child: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- child_id: long (nullable = true)
```

I would like to wrap the *child* struct above into an *Array*, as shown in the box below.

```
root
 |-- child: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- child_id: long (nullable = true)
```

I tried to define an UDF:

```
//the two lines below are an example, in real i get the Dataframe from an  external library. 
val seq = sc.parallelize(Seq("""{ "child": { "child_id": 1}}"""))
val df = sqlContext.read.json(seq)

val myUDF = udf((x: Row) => Array(x))
val df2 = df.withColumn("children",myUDF($"child"))
```

But i get an exception: "*Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported*"

I'm working with **Spark 2.1.1**.

The real DataFrame is very complex, is there a solution that allow modifying the schema without listing the name or the position of the fields in the child table? For the same reason I also would rather not to map to explicit case classes.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `array` inbuilt function to get your desired result as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df2 = df.withColumn("child", array("child"))
```

this will update the same column, if you want it in separate column then do

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df2 = df.withColumn("children", array("child"))
```

Comment: No :) I guess you are not. Thanks for the acceptance and upvotes :)